# R Waterfall chart x values

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Im new and self taught to R, so please bear with me.

I am trying to plot waterfall charts with the following data frame [called `balancefinal`]:

```
X1  X2  type    end start   id
Actual  1.09112725  Actual  1.09112725  0   1
Actual Est  1.345028317 Estimated   1.345028317 0   2
Factor1 -0.28842558 Change  1.056602737 1.345028317 3
Factor2 -0.091360211    Change  0.965242526 1.056602737 4
Factor3 0.110622374 Change  1.0758649   0.965242526 5
Factor4 0.227710095 Change  1.303574995 1.0758649   6
Factor5 0.27353189  Change  1.577106884 1.303574995 7
Factor6 0.006879353 Change  1.583986238 1.577106884 8
Factor7 0.135077259 Change  1.719063497 1.583986238 9
Factor8 0.00591948  Change  1.724982976 1.719063497 10
Factor9 0.077394066 Change  1.802377042 1.724982976 11
Factor10    0.05212228  Change  1.854499322 1.802377042 12
Factor11    0.062991126 Change  1.917490448 1.854499322 13
Actual Est  1.836828552 Estimated   0   1.917490448 14
ActualB 1.278994    Actual  1.278994    0   15
```

I have tried the following code (rearranging code from [here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/))

Code for stacking x variable names: `strwr <- function(str) gsub(" ", "\n", str)`

```
  ggplot(balancefinal, aes(X1, fill = type)) + geom_rect(aes(x = X1,  xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start), colour = "black") + 
    scale_fill_manual (values =c("#90353B", "#1A476F","burlywood1"))  + scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(balancefinal$X1), labels = strwr(levels(balancefinal$X1))) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), axis.text= element_text(size = 8), plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous("", labels = dollar, breaks = seq(0, max(balancefinal$start) + 0.25, by = 0.25))
```

Ideally, the order of the variables in the x axis should be Actual, Actual Est, Factor1,...,Factor11, Actual Est, ActualB. This is not the case, it seems that the boxes representing the values of X2 are correct but the order of the labels is not. Do you have any idea why this may be happening? Any help/hint would be hugely appreciated.

PS:Sorry if it is a basic question. If you think it is let me know and I will remove it.

Comment: I think your example is not fully reproducible. What do you mean 'correct order of labels'? Is R suppose to read your mind? Does the order happen to be the same as `levels(dollar)` (assuming it's a factor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your data:

```
text <- "X1  X2  type    end start   id
Actual  1.09112725  Actual  1.09112725  0   1
Actual Est  1.345028317 Estimated   1.345028317 0   2
Factor1 -0.28842558 Change  1.056602737 1.345028317 3
Factor2 -0.091360211    Change  0.965242526 1.056602737 4
Factor3 0.110622374 Change  1.0758649   0.965242526 5
Factor4 0.227710095 Change  1.303574995 1.0758649   6
Factor5 0.27353189  Change  1.577106884 1.303574995 7
Factor6 0.006879353 Change  1.583986238 1.577106884 8
Factor7 0.135077259 Change  1.719063497 1.583986238 9
Factor8 0.00591948  Change  1.724982976 1.719063497 10
Factor9 0.077394066 Change  1.802377042 1.724982976 11
Factor10    0.05212228  Change  1.854499322 1.802377042 12
Factor11    0.062991126 Change  1.917490448 1.854499322 13
Actual Est  1.836828552 Estimated   0   1.917490448 14
ActualB 1.278994    Actual  1.278994    0   15"

text <- gsub("[ ]+"," ",text)
text <- gsub("Actual Est", "ActualEst",text) # Ugh, dealing with spaces in a name.

balancefinal <- read.delim(textConnection(text), header = TRUE, sep=" ",strip.white=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
strwr <- function(str) gsub(" ", "\n", str)
dollars <- paste0("$",seq(0, max(balancefinal$start) + 0.25, by = 0.25))
```

So you have to be careful with factors in R.  You have a repeated factor 'ActualEst' twice, ggplot2 will combine them, and list them alphabetically on your chart (how R factored your data).

Let's refactor and rename the extra level:

```
# You have to be careful how you define factors in R:
balancefinal$X1 = as.character(balancefinal$X1)
balancefinal$X1[14] = "ActualEst2"  # We need to make this a new factor (unique label)

# Here we reorder your factors in X1
balancefinal$X1_1 <- factor(balancefinal$X1, as.character(balancefinal$X1))

ggplot(balancefinal, aes(X1_1, fill = type)) +
  geom_rect(aes(x = X1_1,  xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start), colour = "black") + 
  scale_fill_manual (values =c("#90353B", "#1A476F","burlywood1")) +
  scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(balancefinal$X1_1), labels = strwr(levels(balancefinal$X1_1))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(),
    axis.text= element_text(size = 8), plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous("", labels = dollars, breaks = seq(0, max(balancefinal$start) + 0.25, by = 0.25))
```

Now it works, albeit you have 'ActualEst2' instead of 'ActualEst'.